# Script to Change Pronunciations on Mac

Tags: macos, osx-lion, say

So I've been looking around on how to change how my mac says things, I have found my answer but what I need is some help with the coding. Here is what I want to do:

> - Create a list of word pairs.
> - Create a script that substitutes words in its parameter list according to your word-pairs list, and passes the modified parameter list to "/usr/bin/say".

This is a quick copy of https://superuser.com/q/170041/106990 and I have very little coding know-how and would like some help. I don't care in what language.

Comment: How do you want to use it? From the command line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change how OS X's 'say' pronounces a word?](http://superuser.com/questions/169964/how-can-i-change-how-os-xs-say-pronounces-a-word)

Answer (score 1):

Create a file `say.sh` and enter the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
TEXT="$@"
while read line ; do
    TEXT="$( echo $TEXT | sed "s${line}g" )"
done < "/path/to/rules.txt"
/usr/bin/say $TEXT
```

Make this file executable from the command line by running `chmod +x say.sh`

---

Create a file `rules.txt` where you specified in the above script (4th line) and enter substitution rules like the following:

```
|one thing|other thing|
|foo|Apple|
|Apple Mac|Apple Macintosh|
```

The order of rules is important, as they are applied in order.

Run as `/path/to/say.sh foo Mac` to have your Mac say "Apple Macintosh"

Comment: Of course, this completely ignores e.g. word boundaries of case-insensitivity. But your question really didn't contain enough information on how to handle those.

Comment: I want to be able to have it execute to before the normal say file so I can change pronunciation of the normal say command, if that is possible, so I could have the changes in Safari or Mail.

Comment: @user these applications use programming Apis internal to OS x and don't use say. You'd need to patch your operating system and that is more or less impossible. It seems you're out of luck then.

Comment: Oh, well that is very disheartening. Not much I can do.