# Applescript - Customize text-to-speech pronunciation of Chinese characters

Tags: find-and-replace, applescript, input, text-to-speech, chinese

I would like to change the default pronunciation of certain Chinese characters and phrases using Applescript. This would be an improvisation of the suggestion given by @JRobert over [here](https://superuser.com/a/170041).

The basic idea is this:

1. Set as record a list of specific phrases and/or characters in
   context whose pronunciations I would like to change. If possible,
   maintain the list of term-pronunciation pair on a .txt file and read
   that into the script.

   set x to {phrase:"《傳》", utter:"ㄓㄨㄢˋ"}
2. Run through the list in such a way that every time a string that matches a phrase in the record is input into "say", the original string is replaced by its phonetic substitute.

Is there an easy way to do this?